# masking objects rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, masking

I am using objects (those in image below) to mask parts of others (3D modeled holes in ground and wall) in camera motion tracking . Those masking objects are in different "background" layer, so **they are not rendered in final image** which is fine.

However, when I am watching the rendering process, it takes quite long to those masking objects to be rendered, so my question is, is there a way to let them only mask rendered 3D objects and not catch any light, to not be rendered at all?

I guess the process looks like this for each frame:

1. the 3D model is rendered (just the parts not hidden by masks)
2. mask layer is rendered (the one you can see in image below - you can see last three tiles to be rendered in bottom left corner)

In short, by those masking objects shapes (image below) I just want to tell Blender what parts of the 3D objects it should not bother to render. I don't need those masking objects to catch and bounce any light or so = don't take render time.

Using Cycles.

Sample rendered image - just masking layer :
[image: Masking render]

Comment: While it might be obvious to you, it is impossible to guess what is we are looking at in the image posted, or what the masks look like or what it is that you want to optimize. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: @cegaton thanks for suggestion. edited, hope it makes more sense